# How do I create a dynamic SELECT clause using JDBCTemplate and MapParameterSource?

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data, jdbctemplate

Our non-JPA repositores in Spring have (and will have) a lot of similar boilerplate code. To minimize possible human error and cut down on mind-numbing work, we want to write a few utility classes. To that extend, I need to be able to insert columns into a select statement.

What I could do:

```
final String sql = "SELECT " + myDynamicColumn + " FROM ....."
```

This works. However, we're using jdbcTemplate and MapSqlParameterSource, and as such, something I'd like to be able to do, would be this:

```
final String sql = "SELECT :myColumn FROM ...";
sqlParams.add("myColumn","realColumnName");
...
```

This however does not work, because during execution any parameter gets put into single quotes, which is not valid SQL. This makes the code non-transparent, since it forces me to mix both styles.

Is there a way to "tell" MapSqlParameterSource that that specific element needs to be inserted as-is, without formatting it?